# Refer to type in different file in JSDoc without importing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm writing JavaScript (ES6) code in Visual Studio Code and enabled VSCode's type checking as explained in the [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files).

When referring to a type that is defined in another file (`Track` in the example below), I get an error like *[js] Cannot find name 'Track'* at the JSDoc reference to that type unless I import it. When I import this type, I get an error from ESLint: *[eslint] 'Track' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)*

I don't want to disable the ESLint rule. Is there a way to import the type *only* for the type checks in VSCode?

```js
import Track from "./Track";

export default class TrackList {

/**
 * Creates a new track list.
 * @param {Iterable<Track>} tracks the tracks to include
 */
constructor(tracks) {
    this._tracks = tracks ? Array.from(tracks) : [];
}
...
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `Track` to the [globals](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) in ESLint config?

Comment: Or [disable rules with comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) in ESLint

Comment: @Alex Adding `Track` to globals does not help. JSDoc needs a reference to the source code. Disabling rules would help, but I don't like to disable the rule entirely as this would limit the use of ESLint. Disabling it only for certain names works via the [varsignorepattern](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern) option but using this pattern in every other file would be rather ugly.

Comment: @ralfstx did you try Alex's link to the comment syntax to disable rules for a specific line or section?  I had trouble getting the single-line versions to work but I was able to use a disable comment, then import, then an enable comment, and I get the best of both worlds -- eslint checks everything else, and Intellisense uses the correct type information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `import("%YOUR_LIB%").%TYPE%`:

```js
export default class TrackList {

/**
 * Creates a new track list.
 * @param {Iterable<import("./Track").Track>} tracks the tracks to include
 */
constructor(tracks) {
    this._tracks = tracks ? Array.from(tracks) : [];
}
...
```

Comment: Perfect... and hideous. `;^)` How in the world did you come across that?

Comment: I've got this hint from some IDE dev. team, when I've opened a ticket that code completion works not as expected.

Answer (score 18):

I have a similar problem and here is how I solved it.

```
//file.d.ts
export interface Foo {
    bar: number;
}

export as namespace Baz;
```

Doing this will make the `Baz` namespace global so you can use it anywhere without importing

```
/**
 * @param {Baz.Foo} arg 
 */
function test(arg) {

}
```

Now you get intellisense and type checking in VSCode.
[image: VS Code]

Comment: I find this answer fascinating, thank you for that. This way we can keep types in a single d.ts file and "import" them across the codebase within JSDoc without actually having to write "import" everywhere. What's not to like?

Answer (score 6):

Just to keep this topic updated:

With [typescript@2.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/67) you will be able to import JSDoc `typedef`s, that are automatically exported.

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23692#issuecomment-384599074) with a real working example.
Also you can walk along webpack's code to see how they used JSDoc and typescript to statically chech their pure JS sourcecode base. here is [their issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7122) with JSDoc conventions where you can get insipration.

Comment: To make it easier, applying this answer to your case it would mean adding `/** @typedef { import('./Track').default } Track */`

Answer (score 1):

The workaround to disable es-lint warning: using `//eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars` comment in the end of line with unused import.

```
import Track from './Track'; //eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

export default class TrackList {

/**
 * Creates a new track list.
 * @param {Iterable<Track>} tracks the tracks to include
 */
constructor(tracks) {
  this._tracks = tracks ? Array.from(tracks) : [];
}
...
```

Comment: Except the import was only shown to get around the problem of linting going "I have no idea what `Track` is". By actually writing import code, there is suddenly a _code_ dependency between the two files, instead of only a _typing_ dependency. This file will now cause the JS engine to _run_ the module that `Track` lives in, even though it shouldn't.